# Oracle Cloud ATP database missing from cloud account

Tags: oracle, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

when i tried accessing one of my APEX applications I developed on oracle cloud.

I get this error

The database service named: |ocid1.tenancy.oc1..aaaaaaaacwex5sqkhi7kwsb5s664n6brmhrjvhhsxduw35l2rzahhsa7pyaa-tmohammedb|re| does not exist

And When I logged into my Oracle Cloud account, to my dismay, My oracle ATP database is not more available. I didn't get notification either from Oracle support.

Under My resources the database is listed as stopped.

[image]

But when i Click on it it shows "Error retrieving values"

[image]

Can anyone help me with recovering the database.

Regards

Comment: did you have a free account ? normally they warn you by email when the database is going to be removed. If it is not a free account, I guess you might contact Support, which is associated to your cloud payment subscription

Comment: Free tier account and instance type paid. I thought autonomous database is part of always free service ..is it not?

Answer (score 1):

Looking into this, I came across a thread you created via Cloud Customer Connect where your question was answered. I'd recommend reviewing and following up there - https://cloudcustomerconnect.oracle.com/posts/44c1ada213

TLDR - your database environment is up and running .. but it will go away for sure since you are not using the free tier database. You should get your data out of that system, it will go away. Please give this the appropriate priority